# Necessary conditions for unique minimum of quadratic functions over convex compact sets

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am curious if there are any results that give *both sufficient and necessary* conditions for having a unique solution to the quadratic optimization problem
$$
min_{x} f(x)\\
\text{subject to }x\in K
$$
with $f(x)=x^\top M x + x^\top q$, $M=M^\top$, and $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and compact.

I know that since $f$ is continuous and $K$ is compact, the problem has at least one solution. Also a sufficient condition for having unique solution is that $M$ is positive definite. But are there any results that give both sufficient and necessary conditions?

Comment: Is $M$ assumed to be positive semidefinite?

Comment: @gerw In general there is no assumption on $M$ other than being symmetric. If it's both necessary and sufficient that $M>0$, then it's possible to assume that.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question @Mehran?